# bilinear sampling in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-2

theano.tensor.nnet.abstract_conv.bilinear_upsampling(input, ratio=None, frac_ratio=None, batch_size=None, num_input_channels=None, use_1D_kernel=True)
I need to replace this theano backend command with Keras 2.0 or tensorflow backend. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found a solution?